# CSS tr background not working IE7

Tags: javascript, css, background, tablerow, alternating

The tr background property doesn't seem to work in IE7. I want to make the bgcolor of the row alternating and then have it a different color when the mouse is on the row. So I can't use table `tbody tr.d1 td{background:#f1f1f1;}` because `tbody tr.d1 td:hover{background:#f1f1f1;}` will only affect the color of the cell, not the whole row...
Anyone has an idea on how to make this code work?:

```
<html>
    <head>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js" ></script>      
      <style type="text/css">
        table tbody tr.d1 td{background:transparent;}
        table tbody tr.d2 td{background:transparent;}
        table tbody tr.d1{background:#f1f1f1; color:#363636;}
        table tbody tr.d2{background:white; color:#363636;} 
        table tbody tr.d1:hover, tr.d2:hover{background:#FFF5C3; color:#FF7260;} 
      </style>        
    </head>
<body>  
    <table  class="sortable">
      <thead> 
        <tr>
          <th >Index</th> 
          <th><span class="nowrap">Parameter Name</span></th>
          <th><span class="nowrap">Parameter Value</span></th>
          <th><span class="nowrap">Page Name</span></th>
          <th ><span class="nowrap">Page Name</span></th>
          <th ><span class="nowrap">Page Name</span></th>
          <th ><span class="nowrap">Page Name</span></th>
          <th class="sorttable_nosort scrollbarCol"></th> 
        </tr>
      </thead>  
      <tbody>
            <tr class="d1">
              <td>4_1</td> <td>gfryn</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d2">
              <td>4_2</td> <td>aegr</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="d1">
              <td>4_3</td> <td>ryj</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d2">
              <td>4_4</td> <td>styj</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d1">
              <td>4_5</td> <td>rth</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d2">
              <td>4_6</td> <td>srhfr</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d1">
              <td>4_7</td> <td>sryh</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="d2">
              <td>4_8</td> <td>et5h</td> <td>4_2</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> <td>4_3</td> 
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[EDIT] 
what would a javascript workarround look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

OLD: table tbody tr.d1:hover td, tr.d2:hover td {background-color:#FFF5C3; color:#FF7260;}

```
  table tbody tr:hover, tr:hover td {background-color:#FFF5C3; color:#FF7260;}
```

---

replace it in your code:

```
<style>
        table tbody tr.d1{background-color:#f1f1f1; color:#363636;}
        table tbody tr.d2{background-color:white; color:#363636;} 
        table tbody tr:hover, tr:hover td{background-color:#FFF5C3; color:#FF7260;} 
</style>
```

---

the js (jQuery) workaround

```
$(tr).hover( 
  function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
  }
);
```

css:

```
.highlight {background-color:#FFF5C3; color:#FF7260;}
```

Comment: tr:hover, tr:hover td { background-color: red; } - this is working in IE7

Comment: well not in my IE7. I have posted the entire code in the question and if i change the `table tbody tr.d1:hover, tr.d2:hover{background:#FFF5C3; color:#FF7260;}` to your line, there is no change at all...

Comment: I replaced the code, only the alternating colors worked. jQuery could be good too...

Comment: in your html there is no DOCTYPE set

Comment: [http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html], fyi: [http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype]

Answer (score 2):

IE7 always is a headache, I don't know why IE7 understand `background:transparent` in this way but with `*background-color:none` finally works:

http://jsfiddle.net/NAGyt/1/

And for the `td:hover` I hope this can be helpful for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/NAGyt/2/

Anyway, check out [these](http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/css-ie-hover.shtml) [links](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762) for more information on `:hover` in IE7.

Comment: Thank you! the alternating colors works by changing `background:transparent` to `*background-color:none` but the `:hover` stil isn't working...

Comment: yeah its a real pain for such a insignificant small feature :(

Comment: I updated my answer with a few links that maybe could help you. But I still thinking that you should make a javascript only for IE6-8 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted seems to work perfectly in IE7 with alternating row color and background color change of  on hover.

For IE7, are you using IE8 with developer toolbar to test your code. If yes then try setting:

Browser Mode to: IE 7
Document Mode: IE 7 Standards

By default the document mode turns to Quirks mode when you change the Browser mode to IE 7.
So set both the settings and then test your code.